# Elements not being appended to array in loop

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ksh

I am writing a Bash Shell script, which reads a bunch of lines from a file, and tries to append each line to an array, thus:

```
# counter variable    
i=0

cat doc.txt | while read -r line; do
    myArr[i]="$line"
    ((i=i+1))
done
```

The file `doc.txt` contains one word in every line. When I print the array (through `echo ${myArr[@]}` or `for x in ${myArr[@]};do echo $x; done`), my array seems to be empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**Edit**: I also tried doing this in Ksh, with the same results. An answer in either Bash or Ksh is acceptable, since I seem to be having the same issue in both.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `ksh`? In `bash`, for instance, the `while` loop runs in a subprocess, which means `myArr` isn't modified in the shell that runs the pipeline. Try `while read -r line; do ...; done < doc.txt`.

Comment: The notorious `cat file | cmd`... Either use redirection suggested by @chepner or use `shopt -s lastpipe` before the loop (redirection is much better).

Comment: And [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: Which specific version of ksh did you get the same result in? Unlike bash, ksh *does* (typically) run the last component of a pipeline in the same shell that was running the script previously. (Not that you should be using `cat file` at all -- `<file` after your `done` not only avoids this bug but is also more efficient).

Comment: Also, are you attempting to execute the script, *then* check the contents of the array? That won't work for the same reason `cat | while` would fail; you are setting the array in a separate process than the one in which you look at the array.

Comment: @chepner No, I am trying to print through the same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the `while` loop in a subshell, so any changes you make to the array disappear once that shell exits. Use input redirection instead:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    myArr+=("$line")
done < doc.txt
```

If you using `bash` 4.0 or later, you can use a single command

```
readArray -t myArr < doc.txt
```